# issue about JComboBox itemListener in two level JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jmenubar, itemlistener

I'm new, but I was searching and now it's time for me to ask you mates.
I have this simple app in java, which includes itemListener for JComboBox.
I have no idea why but, it doesn't listen, but when i put JComboBox upper in hierarchy it works, and itemListener works fine. Any ideas why it doesn't work in lower level?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class Notatnik extends JFrame {

JMenuBar menu;
JMenu tools, fontColor;
JComboBox<String> colors;

    public Notatnik() {
        this.setSize(500, 400);

        menu = new JMenuBar();
        tools = new JMenu("tools");
        fontColor = new JMenu("Font color");
            colors = new JComboBox<String>();
        colors.addItem("red");
        colors.addItem("green");
        colors.addItem("blue");

        colors.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getItem().toString());
            }
        });

        fontColor.add(colors);
        tools.add(fontColor);
        menu.add(tools);
        this.setJMenuBar(menu);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, you're adding a JComboBox to a JMenu?

Comment: My mate added, I'm just thinking "hey, is that even possible?"
So I checked and added to JMenu, and after that to JMenuBar, with JMenuBar it works, and with JMenu it doesn't. So... Is it possible to add to JMenu and then how to control it?

Comment: Don't think its possible (without a lot of hacking to the UI). Instead I would: 1) just display JRadioMenuItem for each color. 2) display a  JOptionPane with the colors in a combo box added to the option pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add a `JComboBox` to a `JMenu` component (without destroying the listeners). Therefore, I changed the implementation a bit:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Stackoverflow {

    // Initialize the color to your desired choice.
    private static Color color = Color.RED;

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stackoverflow | Answer");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            final JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
            // This is just for debugging.
            final JLabel currentColor = new JLabel(color.getRed() + "r " + color.getGreen() + "g " + color.getBlue() + "b");
            final JMenuItem item01 = new JMenuItem("Red");
            final JMenuItem item02 = new JMenuItem("Green");
            final JMenuItem item03 = new JMenuItem("Blue");
            item01.addActionListener((event -> {
                Stackoverflow.setColor(currentColor, Color.RED);
            }));
            item02.addActionListener((event -> {
                Stackoverflow.setColor(currentColor, Color.GREEN);
            }));
            item03.addActionListener((event -> {
                Stackoverflow.setColor(currentColor, Color.BLUE);
            }));
            final JMenu parent = new JMenu("Color");
            parent.add(currentColor);
            parent.add(item01);
            parent.add(item02);
            parent.add(item03);
            menu.add(parent);
            menuBar.add(menu);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(500, 400);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public static void setColor(final JLabel label, final Color color) {
        // Update the text of the specified JLabel. Edit this part to change the actual font color.
        label.setText(color.getRed() + "r " + color.getGreen() + "g " + color.getBlue() + "b");
        Stackoverflow.color = color;
    }
}
```

I know that the code is not tidy or efficient, but it works just fine. Before I forget it, you should definetly visit [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) article about when to inherit a class.

Comment: Thank you very much, my curiosity was fulfilled. :)

Comment: @KanoidSan No problem. :)